# Partition on existing table getting an error "infinite recursion detected in rules"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, data-partitioning

--Existing Data

```
create table tbl_Master
(
    col_Date date not null,
    id int not null,
    value int not null
);

insert into tbl_Master values('2021-01-14',10,21);
insert into tbl_Master values('2020-09-30',11,22);
insert into tbl_Master values('2021-11-28',12,23);
```

--alter table name

```
alter table tbl_Master rename to tbl_Master_old;
```

--Create Master table again with Partition by range

```
create table tbl_Master(
    col_Date date not null,
    id int not null,
    value int not null
) partition by range (col_Date);
```

--Function:

```
create or replace function fn_create_partition(col_Date date) returns void
as 
$body$

declare v_startDate date := date_trunc('month', col_Date)::date;
declare v_EndDate date := (v_startDate + interval '1 month')::date;
declare tableName text := 'tbl_Master_Part_' || to_char(col_Date, 'YYYYmm');

begin
    if to_regclass(tableName) is null then
    execute format('create table %I partition of tbl_Master for values from (%L) to (%L)', tableName, v_startDate, v_EndDate);
    end if;
end;
$body$ 
language plpgsql;
```

--Create Partition tables for existing data

```
do
$$
declare rec record;
begin
    for rec in select distinct date_trunc('month', col_Date)::date yearmonth from tbl_Master_old 
    loop
    perform fn_create_partition(rec.yearmonth);
    end loop;
end
$$;
```

--Insert backup data

```
insert into tbl_Master (col_Date, id, value) select * from tbl_Master_old;
```

--When I insert record

```
insert into tbl_Master values('2021-02-22',12,22);
```

**Getting an error**:

`ERROR:  no partition of relation "tbl_master" found for row DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (col_date) = (2021-02-22).`

So I have created rule for this:

--Rule

```
create or replace rule rule_fn_create_partition as on insert
to tbl_Master
do instead 
(
select fn_create_partition(NEW.col_Date);
insert into tbl_Master values(New.*)
);
```

--When I insert record

```
insert into tbl_Master values('2021-02-22',12,22);
```

**Getting an error**:

`ERROR:  infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "tbl_master"`

Answer (score 0):

The rule contains an `INSERT`, so that is an infinite recursion.

You cannot have PostgreSQL automatically create partitions as you insert data. It just doesn't work. Triggers won't work either. The problem is that that would require modifying the underlying table while the insert is in progress.